# Order of convergence in a linear equation

Tags: convergence-divergence

This is a general question about using the $\mathcal{O}$ idea to say something about the sign of coefficient. Suppose I have
$$x:=\frac{1}{b^2}\gamma(b)-\frac{1}{b^3}\beta(b)$$ and $b\in (b_0,+\infty)$ where $b_0 >1$.
$\gamma(b)$ and $\beta(b)$ are bounded continous functions . $\gamma(b)$  bounded above by $\bar{\gamma}>0$ and below by $\underline{\gamma}>0$. $\beta(b)$ is also bounded above by $\bar{\beta}>0$ and bounded below by $\underline{\beta}<0$ . Can i say that the sign of $x$ will be positive for large $b$ . Or more precisely, there exists a $\hat{b}$ such that for $b>\hat{b}$, the statement should hold?

My attempt:
Since $\underline{\gamma}>0$, there exists a $\hat{b}$, such that 
$$\underline{\gamma}-\frac{\bar{\beta}}{\hat{b}}\ge0$$. Now for all $b>\hat{b}$, the expression will be positive. Is my reasoning okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say anything about the sign of $x$. Consider $x=\frac{\sin(b)}{b^2}$ and $\gamma(b)=\frac{1}{b^2}$.

Comment: clarification: is beta=sin(b) and gamma=1/b^2. And they are additive. Won the first term be much larger in magnitude than the second term for large b. ?

Comment: I was thinking of $\beta(b)=0$, as $\sin(b)=\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: I provided more information of the functions involved.

Comment: With the correct statements, you found the answer. Notice that you didn't use the $\mathcal{O}$. Be careful with them. They're useful for calculations, but not so much for properties.